# Finding points that are not differentiable

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given $f(x)= \lfloor x\rfloor + \lfloor-x\rfloor$ and $g(x)= x - \lfloor x\rfloor$ 
The homework question askes me to find the points that are non differentiable. 
I know how to do this from looking at the graphs because it would just be the points in which sharp turns or undefined, verticle tangent slopes, occur. But how would I find this algebraically?

Comment: Points are not differentiable, functions are.

Comment: yes i know that

Comment: OK, just checking in, because of the title.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Please ... you would never say the point $1$ is differentiable if $f$ is differentiable at $1.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $n$ be any integer. If $n<x<n+1$, then $f(x)=\lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor -x \rfloor=n+(-(n+1))=-1$. If $x$ is an integer, then $f(x)=\lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor -x \rfloor=x+(-x)=0$. So you can rewrite $f(x)$ as

$$f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      0 & x \in \mathbb{Z} \\
      -1 & \text{else}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

So you can see $f$ is constant (and thus differentiable) everywhere except the integers, where it is not even continuous (the limit as $x$ approaches an integer is $-1$, the value of $f$ at an integer is $0$).

Try doing a similar argument for $g$.

Comment: can you walk me through g(x) because we have another two problems that built of this but include rational functions